# What framework should I use to multi-label classification with thousands of labels

Tags: multilabel-classification, fasttext, bert-language-model, ludwig

I'm working now on multi-label classification service and currently I have prepared training dataset. The problem is that current training dataset has a lot of different labels (around 80 000).

At first I tried BERT from Google through Simpletransformers:
https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers#minimal-start-for-multilabel-classification

But the problem is that you need there for each input binary matrix with labels so that means I need for each keyword to train huge binary matrix with length 80 000. So it's not usable.

Then I tried Ludwig:
https://uber.github.io/ludwig/examples/#multi-label-classification

But after first test it seems like Ludwig remember only first 10 000 most frequent labels so it's not usable for my case too.

Now I'm trying it with **FastText** and it seems it works well, just need a lot of CPUs and computational time.

My question is if you think FastText is good option for my case or if you can recommend me something else when I do multi-label classification with so much labels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fasttext is a good option. You can use Google collab. In spite of more CPUs, you can select runtime -> change runtime type -> GPU/TPU.

To use fasttext in Google collab, you can start with following code snippet:

```
!wget https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/archive/{version}.zip
!unzip {version}.zip
%cd fastText-{version}
!make
```